# Is the whole of an exe in the Logical address space while execution?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

When I run an exe, is the whole of the exe logically in the virtual memory, but only a few pages mapped to their actual frames, so when a page that is not mapped is evoked, a fault occurs and we bring the frame in memory, evicting some other frame?
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Depends on the definition of “a few”. And “evicting some other frame” does not happen unless you’re low on physical memory. As long as there’s enough memory, the number of used pages will simply grow.

Comment: Assuming, of course that my physical memory is not enough, else the whole process could be loaded in RAM..

Comment: Depending on the size of the executable, the operating system may decide not to load the entire executable even if there is enough physical memory, simply because loading takes time that adds to the application’s initialization time. The larger the application, the less likely the application will use the entire code in one session.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly system specific. However, in most systems an Executable file consists of instructions for setting up the process address space. The whole of the EXE is not mapped to the process address space.

In some cases (and on some systems) the EXE contain data that is mapped to the address space and the EXE serves as the page file for that data (e.g. code, and read only data).

In the case of uninitialized data, the EXE contains just instructions to allocate those pages and they have to be mapped to the page file.

So there is data in the EXE that is not mapped to the process address space and there is data in the address space that has no mapping to the EXE.